# Expand persistent live USB to full disk?

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I've seen multiple threads on how to expand a Live persistent Ubuntu USB to use more than 4 GB.

What I can't quite determine, is if there's a way to expand the *current* running Ubuntu USB to full disk.

In other words, I am currently running Ubuntu on a 32GB USB stick.  Can I expand that, while using it?  Or do I have to take some steps and use a second USB stick to expand my current version. (I also assume expanding my current USB to full disk will overwrite any data currently on it and I'll start from scratch?)

Comment: The 4BG limit is set by the FAT filesystem. Any change to the filesystem (also known as *formatting some other filesystem*) will definitely destroy all your data. There are alternatives to use 32GB Ubuntu, like using a small installUSB to install Ubuntu onto the 32GB stick.

Comment: @user535733 I just started using Ubuntu so I'm fine with overwriting everything, was just asking to make sure on that point. What's smallUSB, a program that would flash the Ubuntu OS to the stick and allow me to use all the storage with persistence?

Comment: No, it's merely using a smaller USB stick for your LiveUSB. Use that installer to actually install Ubuntu. But instead of installing to a hard drive, you install to the 32GB stick. It's *real* Ubuntu, not live-with-persistence. It might be a bit slow, and it might wear out your 32GB drive in a year or so.

Comment: @user535733 - I think I understand - so I flash the Ubuntu OS on to a USB.  Then start running Ubuntu (using the "try Ubuntu" option when booting).  Then when I'm in *that* Ubuntu, Insert my 32GB stick and choose the "Install Ubuntu" option, and when I do that, it will show me an option to install on the 32Gb stick, and I just choose that to install to and I'm good to go, and can run that 32GB Ubuntu from "Windows" (when booting my Dell, hit F12 and choose to boot from USB)?

Comment: If you do a full install on the USB stick, make sure you know which drive is which.  You will have both your hard drive on the computer and the 32gb usb stick as options to install.  If not careful end up installing on hard drive and wiping all data on it.

Comment: @crip659 yeah I will. Assuming I choose the correct drive, is what I commented above correct? If so, thanks!! I'll try that out :D

Comment: Should work, might have to have the 32gb in at the same time.  After install you will have 'grub' come on first so you can choose windows or ubuntu.

Comment: Afterwards, search this site for "optimize usb" to find suggestions to speed things up and to minimize wear.  Most involve moving things into ram, or limiting some directory access updates.

Comment: @crip659 so it seems to have worked. However, when I take the USB out and start the computer Grub shows up first. I typed Exit, and hit enter and windows disk check started. I skipped that, and windows launched as usual. ...is that normal for my comp. now?

Comment: @user535733 if you wouldn't mind putting your comments in an Answer, I'll mark it. It worked great!

Comment: Grup default install is on sda drive(your hard drive).  Unless the USB stick is in the way or you need the USB connection, I would leave it in as much as possible.  Save wear and tear on connection.

Comment: @BruceWayne: **Full install** to USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive/1122123#1122123

Comment: @C.S.Cameron thanks for that! ... Last question, can a full ubuntu install on a USB be used on any computer? Like I can just take it and plug it in to my PC or laptop or friends laptop and boot from that? Or is that only for the "live" Ubuntu one.

Comment: @BruceWayne: It should boot on any modern Intel/AMD machine that has Ubuntu's minimum spec's and boots BIOS. For a USB that boots BIOS or UEFI see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142544/standard-uses-of-usb-if-ubuntu-is-installed/1142675#1142675 . mkusb is a program that runs on Ubuntu Linux. It can be run on Live USB.