# Installing ubuntu on usb hard disk drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, hard-drive

2019-08-14
Hello

1. I have a "live" version of the latest ubuntu on a thumbdrive
2. My pc is running windows 10 and is a 64 bit windows machine
3. I want to create a usb hdd (hard disk drive) from which I can boot into
   ubuntu
4. I have a concern that if I choose dthe install option when booting from
   the thumb drive with the "live" version that I will destroy i.e. overwrite
   my c: drive.

My question is:  Given the aboved 4 points how do I safely install ubuntu to
another usb hard disk drive from which I can boot.

thank you

Comment: You should familiarize with Ubuntu installer, there are many guides in the interwebs. The installer won't destroy any data by itself. You will reach a point where you have to choose wich disk Ubuntu will be installed on. You have to be shure that you choose the *right* disk.

Comment: The first thing to do before you install anything is to identify your USB HDD. Run `sudo parted -l` and your C: drive is easily identifiable as it will show NTFS partitions. It will also have an *sdx* id, (eg sda) as will your USB drive (eg sdb). You'll also also see from the size which drive is which. So make a note which *sdx* is the right one then go ahead and install.

Comment: [Related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr?rq=1)

Comment: You will need to use the 'something else' option on the installer.  The main is to know which disk is which and to make sure you install to the disk you want as guillermo charmorro said.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? BIOS is relatively easy as you can specify the location of grub2's boot loader in Something Else's partitioning page. But with UEFI that does not work and you have to do a work around & must partition in advance. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Before proceeding DISABLE or UNPLUG your internal drive. It will then be impossible to mess up your internal drive when installing to external drive. For BIOS & UEFI bootable Full install USB drive see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142544/standard-uses-of-usb-if-ubuntu-is-installed/1142675#1142675 For BIOS boot only see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive/1122123#1122123