# Security error while booting Lubuntu from usb

Tags: boot, usb

I tried to create a persistent thumb-drive with Lubuntu 18.04.4 on it using the method presented in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/853839) and it all went pretty well until I tried to boot the new OS. The first try was on a Lenovo Yoga 310 and prompted an error message about a security policy blocking the boot. The second attempt was after I disabled the Secure Boot and nothing happened (brand logo appeared and  that's it). I had a similar result with attempt number 3 on another machine.

EDIT: my goal is to have a bootable USB drive with persistence (i don't want to install ubuntu on my hard drive).

EDIT 2 for more accurate vocabulary

Comment: Install implies to me to a hdd/ssd rather than the creation of a persistent thumb-drive.  I haven't created a persistent image in years, however if I wanted to do it today I'd for sure use `mkusb` which is an option (27 upvote) on your linked page or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: I'm sorry for the inappropriate vocabulary. I did use mkusb to create a thumb-drive, but it won't boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Full Install USB

Another option.

If you want to run Ubuntu from USB just like from an internal drive you can make a full install to USB.

It is safest to first unplug your internal drive and then insert your USB. You can then install as you would to HDD, either automated install or using "something else".

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1) You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.

2) A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.

3) You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.

4) The install to pendrive takes less time.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1) You can update and upgrade.

2) If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in these forums).

3) No ugly startup / install screen.

4) Better security, you can use full encryption

5) You can use proprietary drivers.

6) Hibernation works.

7) A persistent install is limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.

8) Faster boot.

9) You can run VBox and use virtual machines.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed.

**Full Install Methods**

Two methods for creating Full install pendrives: [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb/1051558#1051558) and [How to fully install Ubuntu on USB Flashdrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119700/how-to-fully-install-ubuntu-on-usb-flashdrive/1119713#1119713)

Comment: I absolutely did not know that full install on usb was an option, thank you for your answer. It seems to work okay (albeit the boot is rather slow).

Answer (score 1):

Download  [Lubuntu's ISO file](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/), [Ubuntu's ISO file](https://ubuntu.com/download), or a different [supported 'flavour'](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of an ISO file with a different Desktop Environment (i.e., Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, or Xubuntu).

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be [checked for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) .

The Windows instructions are preferred in your case as the Rufus app provides a clear graphical interface to select persistence and specify how much space on the USB flash drive to use for it.

However, if you don't have access to a Windows PC to generate the LiveUSB with persistence in one pass, you can [use these updated instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) on a Linux PC to manually partition a USB Flash Drive and then configure it as a LiveUSB.

Once you make a LiveUSB for Ubuntu or an Ubuntu 'flavour', you may boot with it and use it as is, or use it to install to your PC's internal or external drive [following these steps](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

However, the latest interim release of Lubuntu (19.10) now uses the Calamares installer; it asks the same questions, and does the same things, but its appearance is different. Therefore, please follow [these instructions for installing Lubuntu 19.10](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html).

Comment: I'm going to edit my question because I haven't been clear. I do not want to install (l)ubuntu on any of my machines, but rather I want a portable OS on a USB drive. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Amended for your updated request.