# ubuntu-studio persistent live usb

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I created a persistent live USB using:

- ubuntustudio 19.10
- mkusb

I follow these simple steps: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

I could setup all my soundcards successfully.

But the /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf does not exist in the USB disk created nor the default user is in audio group so memory allocation does not work and generates error messages.

How to persist an audio.conf file and persist that the default user belongs to audio group in order to fully use the ubuntu studio from the bootable usb disk ? It would allow me to share my ubuntu-studio setup easily using copy/clone of my usb disk.

EDIT: In order to set Realtime permissions go to menu and start ubuntu-studio controls. Click on Realtime permissions and select CPU governor to performance and that's it.

Comment: Try making a Full install to USB, everything works just like an internal install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216182/creating-bootable-usb-with-rufus-will-data-be-lost-after-every-reboot/1216251#1216251

Comment: Did you consider installing it in a usb intead of persistence?

Comment: I'm confused. The persistent live usb works as expected

Comment: From your question it sounded like something did not work as expected. Persistent live USB's do not have all the advantages of Full install USB's. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216182/creating-bootable-usb-with-rufus-will-data-be-lost-after-every-reboot/1216251#1216251

Comment: After creating the persistent-live-usb I could install software and they persisted on usb disk. I could use them in further reboot.

Comment: I made a disk image using dd linux command on my hard drive and could clone the image to a new USB Key using dd on Linux or Rufus on Windows 10.even if the size of the new USB Key is larger.